# Kafka Could not find or load main class Files

Tags: windows, apache-kafka

i try to install kafka but this error occured how can i fix this error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Files\kafka\libs\activation-1.1.1.jar;C:\Program
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\kafka\libs\activation-1/1/1/jar;C:\Program
```

Comment: Do not put Kafka into Program Files. Make the path have no spaces

Comment: hi thanks bro OneCricketeer

Comment: Does it work now?